# C++ OpenCV - Is there no way to remove title bar of a window?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, ubuntu, highgui

I am grabbing and displaying video using OpenCV and all I want is a window without the title bar. I've removed the Tool bar and Status bar but I also want to remove the title bar.
I found some pointers using which I can display the video in fullscreen without title bar but I dont want that.
Is there not any other way to do that?
And I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

[image: This is the present window I am getting]

[image: And this is what I want]

Comment: OpenCV provides `cv2.imshow()` just for debugging purposes, and has no intent to heavy external customization. You can use other Python libraries like [Tkinter](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm)

Comment: My post says I'm working in C++ with OpenCV not Python

Comment: Ok, but still the point remains same, `imshow()` is not much customization friendly, You can search for some light weight GUI library in C++ as well.